# cyrus sasl 2.1.26 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have to build openldap from source as the one provided in repo is a bit old.

I downloaded openldap version 2.4.40. I want it to use cyrus sasl

To install cyrus sasl, I did "sudo apt-get install sasl2-dev"

Now openldap is not able to find cyrus sasl. I get the following error:
    checking sasl/sasl.h...no
    checking for sasl/sasl.h presence...no
    checking sasl.h usability...no
    checking sasl.h presence...no
    configure: error: Could not locate cyrus sasl

1. Did I install cyrus sasl the correct way?
2. I believe I need openldap to point to sasl libraries, but I do not know where they are located. Please help
3. I tried building cyrus sasl too. Downloaded version 2.1.26, but I get the following error: fatal error: des.h: No such file or directory. What do I need to fix this? The cyrus team has asked me to contact ubuntu team to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you installed the wrong package, or at least not the only one you need. Try:  `sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev`

As for "des.h", I have two, and they were installed with the packages:

- libssl-dev: /usr/include/openssl/des.h
- libcrypto++-dev: /usr/include/crypto++/des.h

From: `find /usr/include -name des.h | xargs dpkg -S`

Comment: For those who come across this later, I also found libsasl2-dev was the right package when building Apache ORC.